# Haskell, Create list with user input

Tags: haskell

Hello I need to create a list from the user input and stop when "END" is detected.
I'm learning Haskell so it's a bit confuse with the IO.

I have this code to recursivly add the input in a list and when "END" is write by the user it give the list

```
getList :: [String] -> IO [String]
getList list =  do line <- getLine
                   if line ==  "END"
                      then return list
                      else getList (line : list)
```

and I try to catch the result and print it in this function, it already take two parameter that I didn't code already.

```
checkDebruijn :: Int -> String -> IO ()
checkDebruijn sequence alphabet  = do
    print (getList [])
```

And I call it in the main to test it

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (checkDebruijn 0 "")
```

And I have this error :

```
No instance for (Show (IO [String]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (getList [])
      In the expression: do print (getList [])
      In an equation for ‘checkDebruijn’:
          checkDebruijn sequence alphabet = do print (getList [])
  |
7 |     print (getList [])
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I see that print is :
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
So I don't understand why it wouldn't compile. For me **IO** is an action that the compiler do. So getList :: [String] -> **IO [String]**
IO [String] is when the compiler do an action and return a [String] ?

Comment: Note that your reader will generate a reversed list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main should look like:

```
main = getList [] >>= print
```

where:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Or alternatively:

```
main = do
  xs <- getList []
  print xs
```

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `print` has type

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

and `getList []` has type `IO [String]`, so for `print (getList [])` to typecheck there must be a `Show` instance for `IO [String]`. There is no such instance, which causes the error.

There is a `Show` instance for `[String]` however, so you can call `print` on the list returned by executing `getList []`. You can use `do` notation to bind the result to call print on it:

```
checkDebruijn sequence alphabet  = do
    result <- (getList [])
    print result
```